# Php file included in joomla article duplicates itself

Tags: php, jquery, joomla

I have a php script that works well if it is accessed directly.
http://rezervariturcia.com/DIDIM.php

When i use jumi to include this file in a joomla 3.3.1 article i get the script but it duplicated the whole page in the middle.

Problem here : http://rezervariturcia.com/index.php/antalya?code=DIDIM+BEACH++ELEGANCE,DIDIM,DIDIMELEGA 
 I have tried to remove file by file and if i don`t put the  /jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.js file it works but with no custom view like in the original file. 
Can anyone give me a clue of what shoul i do in this case ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems I can see.  Can't guarantee any of these will fix the specific bug, but something in your code must be conflicting with Jumi, probably bad code.

Firstly, you should not put a `<html>` or `<head>` tag within your content - it is embedded within a page, so these elements will already be set as part of your Joomla template.

Secondly, you should not need any of those jquery scripts in your include page.

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Joomla already calls JQuery in your template.  You certainly do not need to call multiple versions of JQuery.  Note that removing these will mean the JQuery will not work when your page is accessed directly, but it should when placed within your template.

Your site is constantly loading javascripts - not sure why that is, but there must be an infinite loop somewhere.  The above may fix this, but this is causing your site to move at a crawl.

Comment: Thank you. I have removed the 2 js scripts, and its showing fine but without the blitzer theme and the lightbox effect. putting the joomla jquery file into my script it has the same result with duplicating content. I really don`t know what to do next. any ideea?

Comment: @Valy - any changes you make based on an answer, please show so that we can see what you have done. I know you added a link for me on the other JSE website so I suggest you do the same here ;)

Comment: Ok. So. This is the link for the script modified . http://codepad.org/X1vzvGn5#output

Comment: Ok. So. This is the link for the script modified . http://codepad.org/X1vzvGn5#output . The result is this http://rezervariturcia.com/index.php/antalya?code=BUYUK+ANADOLU+DIDIM+RESORT,DIDIM,ANDIDRES . So now i have no tabs . Installed one plugin to disable mootools, bootstrap and jquery. You can see in the view source. Installed jquery integrator and the result is -- no tabs and no lightbox.How this site that uses the same script has made it work? http://www.123travel.ro/index.php/turcia/alanya/?location=ALANYA&hotel=ALAIYE_KLEOPATRA_HOTEL&APART&hotelid=ALANYA_ALKLEO any sugestions?